# WebView2 PDF get current page

Tags: winforms, pdf, webview2, current-page

I just can find the way to get a PDF current page number displayed in a WebView2 (C# Winform .Net 6 project).

I have search in Microsoft site and on the web and didn't find any information regarding that specific point.

Anyone?

Comment: What version of WebView2 are you using? Did you update to `1.0.1418.22`? The current page is shown (editable) in the PDF toolbar. The Table of Contents is also available

Comment: Please add more information to this post and what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Try sending key strokes **Ctrl+Alt+G**, then **Ctrl+C** and get it in the **Clipboard_ContentChanged** event. After that fill the clipboard with the previous text object. I did this in my WinUI project with .net 7 / 8. It works. This is the only way as java script returns null and no direct method is given to get the current page number.